# Landscape in Nav Based app ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

i'm in really bad situation, i have to submit my app, but i have discovered one problem :

My app is a Nav based app, in this app i want only one controller to be able to landscape :

--> Root Controller --> WelcomeController --> LandscapeController

In the landscape controller i have set two views inside the main view, one is portrait mode to tell the user he has to turn the device, the other is set to landscape (in the main view which is in portrait mode)

I have subclassed my navigation controller : `MyNavController` in which i have set  :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}
```

So the controller on top of the hierarchy decide if the `navController` can rotate or no.

in my app delegate i have set :

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);

}
```

so i can have both orientation on my app.

In the Welcome Controller i have set :

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
    //return (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

Which means the Welcome Controller can only be in portrait mode.

In the Landscape Controller i have set :

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;

}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

so that the landscape Controller can rotate.

I call Landscape controller using :

```
 LandscapeController *aLandscapeController = [LandscapeController] allo] init.... 
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:aLandscapeController animated:YES];
```

It works, but sometimes believe me or not, when i push the landscape Controller and that i turn the device, it is the Welcome Controller which become landscape and take only half of the screen because it can't be in landscape and this so bad to me you can't imagine.

What can i do to avoid that ?

i'll take any help, i'll make donation if i have to.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I can't understand, you push the LandscapeController, and what you get is not even a LandscapeController, it's a WelcomeController? Or do you mean when you return to the WelcomeController, it stays landscape?

Comment: sorry my code is perfectly working, but not for iOS 5 do you have an idea ?

Comment: Doing unsupported things like subclassing a class you aren't supposed to can certainly result in breakage between versions.

Answer (score 0):

Second sentence of the UINavigationController documentation: "This class is not intended for subclassing." Have you tried it without your override to the navigation controller's orientation behavior? Maybe the navigation controller does the right thing by default, which is to query the child controllers to determine what the orientation should be. But by overriding it, you are breaking the correct behavior, which is more complex than you expected during view transitions.

Keep everything the same except use a standard UINavigationController instead of your subclass. Or if your subclass can't be removed for other reasons, for a quick test try commenting out this code:

```
/*- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}*/
```

But you can't rely on anything working right if you subclass a class that the documentation says you shouldn't.